Not able to set custom display name
I'm not able to set a custom display name. Logs seem correct:
Sender: Admin Display Name admin.emailaddress@gmail.com
To: user.mailaddress@gmail.com
But in the email resulted, display name is missing.
I think I used the correct InternetAddress constructor, but it doesn't work. It simply display the email address.
I run on JDK 17 & Spring Boot 3.1.10
//import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
//import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import jakarta.mail.*;
import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import java.util.Properties;


public class EmailService {

    private final static String from = "admin.emailaddress@gmail.com";
    private final static String displayNameFrom = "Admin Display Name";
    private final static String password = "gmail-api-password";
    //@Async("asyncExecutor")
    public void send(){
        Properties props = loadProperties();
        String subject = "Test subject";
        String message = "Hello World";
        String recipientAddress = "user.mailaddress@gmail.com";
        try{
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new jakarta.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
                        }
                    });

            session.setDebug(true);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport();
            //InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from, displayNameFrom); //TODO test

            MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
            mimeMessage.setSender(addressFrom);
            mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
            mimeMessage.setContent(message+ "\r\n", "text/plain");
            if(email.getReplyTo() != null){
                mimeMessage.setReplyTo(new Address[]{new InternetAddress(email.getReplyTo())});
            }

            mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipientAddress));
            transport.connect();
            Transport.send(mimeMessage);
            transport.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
            //System.err.println("email : "+email.toString());
        }
    }

    private Properties loadProperties(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }
}

public class TestDisplayName(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EmailService emailService = new EmailService();
        emailService.send();
    }
}


Here is the solution shown below
Instead of using setSender, you try to use setFrom with the InternetAddress object that includes the display name
Replace:
mimeMessage.setSender(addressFrom);

with:
mimeMessage.setFrom(addressFrom);


Works like a charm. Thanks
